# If I click on the list item, it toggles the .done class on and off

Tags: javascript, event-handling, jquery-selectors, dom-events

I want to have an event that strikes through the text on my `li`

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="5.3 style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
        <li class="bold red">Jello</li>
        <li class="bold red">Spinach</li>
        <li class="bold red">Rice</li>
        <li class="bold red">Birthday Cake</li>
        <li class="bold red">Candles</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="5.2 script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

My JS

```
 var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
 list.addEventListener("click", function(e){
 list.classList.toggle("done");
 })
```

I have tried:

```
var list = document.querySelector("li");
```

it only gets the first li obviously, so I tried
`querySelectorAll` it isn't working it tells me the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined"

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). You already tagged this with jQuery, which makes stuff like this **a lot** easier.

Comment: jQuery is fading out and MVC is taking over. It's better to learn the basic IMO

Comment: yeah, just the basics that I need to learn. simple event handlers and such. i'll check out on MVC haven't heard about it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach `click` listener to all the `li` elements which you get from `document.getElementsByTagName("li");` as the `getElementsByTagName()` returns you the list of elements with that tag and you need to assign the listener individually to each tag which was missing in your code and hence, error was showing up.

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
 list[i].addEventListener("click", liClick);
}
function liClick(){
  this.classList.toggle("done");
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="5.3 style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
        <li class="bold red">Jello</li>
        <li class="bold red">Spinach</li>
        <li class="bold red">Rice</li>
        <li class="bold red">Birthday Cake</li>
        <li class="bold red">Candles</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="5.2 script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation! :)

Comment: @skylar you can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: yes I will, it just makes me wait for a few minutes
"You can accept an answer in 3 minutes".

Comment: But this doesn't work if we add new elements to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I used `document.querySelectorAll` to select all `li` tags.

Then iterated over the collection of `DOM` objects and attached event to every single one of them.
As you will notice I am using the event inside the `click` event listener to toggle the class `done` on.

Hope this helps

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   list[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("done");
   })
 }
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="5.3 style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
        <li class="bold red">Jello</li>
        <li class="bold red">Spinach</li>
        <li class="bold red">Rice</li>
        <li class="bold red">Birthday Cake</li>
        <li class="bold red">Candles</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="5.2 script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark the accepted answer! This will help other users, who will have a similar issue, find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding an event to each and every `<li>` element add just one event to the `<ul>` that watches what you click on, that will help further when you and new todo's to the list

```
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
ul.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  evt.target.classList.toggle("done");
})
```

But here you also need to watch out of which element you are clicking on. you might just have clicked on the ul, or a deeper element inside of the li element

Comment: Good suggestion, Though as you have said only downside of this is ul will be clickable/other elements can be too. Which I think is not the best solution for what I want to do. (because users might see it and it might cause other problems)

Comment: jQuery solves this very elegant with [$('ul').on('click', 'li', fn)](http://api.jquery.com/on/) i think this teknik is called [event delegation](https://codepen.io/32bitkid/post/understanding-delegated-javascript-events)

Comment: jQuery called it delegate before, changed it to live, deprecated it and now uses `.on()`

Comment: Thanks for all of the inputs. I'll prolly be looking into all of that @Endless

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code below:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].addEventListener("click", liClick); 
}

//function to add the 'line through' style
function liClick() {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
}
```

CSS code below:

```
.done{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Html code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylejs.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get is done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter to-do">

    <button id="enter">Enter</button>

    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="learndom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I followed others Html and CSS, the main thing you need to focus on is the Javascript file. "querySelectorAll("li)" was used to select all the li element list items of the to do list. Then the for loop was use to check through the list and function liClick() takes the style and pass it to the eventlistener().

Answer (score 0):

I know you found your answer, but let me show you a cleaner way to do this:

```
function toggleClassDoneOnAndOff(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === "LI") {
        event.target.classList.toggle("done");
    }
}
ul.addEventListener("click", toggleClassDoneOnAndOff);
```

Hope you enjoy that :)

Answer (score 0):

I used `document.querySelectorAll` to click on the `ul>li` element.

This is the code I am using (I hope this helps):

```js
// Toggle list items on and off when clicked on
var list = document.querySelectorAll('ul>li');

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener("click", toggleList);
}

// function to add the 'line-through' (Strike-through) style
function toggleList(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle("done"); // or this.classList.toggle("done");
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="5.3 style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>
  <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
  <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
  <button id="enter">Enter</button>
  <ul id="list">
    <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
    <li class="bold red">Jello</li>
    <li class="bold red">Spinach</li>
    <li class="bold red">Rice</li>
    <li class="bold red">Birthday Cake</li>
    <li class="bold red">Candles</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="5.2 script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```